# Como sortear apresentação de slides com intervalo definido e depois obter gabarito dos slides apresentados

Tags: vba, macro, powerpoint

For N = 1 To 5
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide Int(Rnd * 4) + 2
Next N

Tenho esse código que apresenta aleatóriamente os slides, porém não consigo definir o tempo de transição entre slides e também preciso ao final ter uma gabarito dos slides que foram apresentados. Alguém consegue ajudar? Abs

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que tanto o sorteio dos slides quanto o tempo de exibição de cada um estejam contemplados corretamente no trecho de código a seguir. Para registrar a ordem de apresentação dos slides, adicionei uma Collection que fez o trabalho duplo de registrar e de não permitir repetição de nenhum dos 5 slides:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub ApresentarAleatóriamenteComRegistro()

    Dim colSlidesApresentados As New Collection
    Dim intSlide As Integer
    Dim lngTimer As Long
    Dim N As Integer
    Dim intSegundos As Integer
    Dim strGabarito As String

    intSegundos = 10

    For N = 1 To 5
        '5 slides serão exibidos aleatoriamente e sem repetição
lblTryAgain:
        intSlide = Int(Rnd * 5) + 1

        On Error GoTo lblErr_Rnd
        'se for gerado número de slide já apresentado, o erro será gerado e
        'o código será levado a nova escolha, sucessivamente.
        colSlidesApresentados.Add intSlide, Key:=CStr(intSlide)    'o objeto Collection não aceita duplicidade de chave (Key)
        On Error GoTo 0

        lngTimer = VBA.Timer
        ' ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide intSlide
        Do While lngTimer + intSegundos > VBA.Timer    'isto manterá a exibição do slide por 10 segundos
            DoEvents
        Loop
    Next N

    'exibir a ordem de apresentação dos slides
    For intSlide = 1 To 5
        strGabarito = strGabarito & colSlidesApresentados(intSlide) & vbNewLine
    Next

    MsgBox strGabarito, vbOKOnly, "Ordem de apresentação dos Slides"

lblExit:
    Exit Sub

lblErr_Rnd:
    Err.Clear
    Resume lblTryAgain    'até que todos os 5 tenham sido sorteados

End Sub
```